# SoftDelete: Can't set flag deletedBy, deletedAt

Tags: next.js, typeorm

When I delete entity with `softDelete` column `deletedAt` and `deletedBy` are null or not set.

If I try `softRemove`, it only sets the `deletedAt` flag.

Here are some code for the entities:

```
@DeleteDateColumn({ name: 'deleted_at'})
deletedAt: Date;

@Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 'deleted_by', nullable: true })
deletedBy: string;
```

And for the services:

```
public async delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
    const talent: Talent = await this.talentRepository.findOne(id);

    if (!talent) throw new NotFoundException(`Talent with ID ${id} Not Found`);

    talent.deletedBy = "John Doe";

    await this.talentRepository.softDelete(talent);
}
```

If I log this service, the parameter `deletedBy` is set to "John Doe" but database is null.

Answer (score 7):

Soft delete will only update the `deletedAt` column. If you want to update the `deletedBy` you should execute it separately as an update query.

From the source code documentation:

softDelete:

```
    /**
     * Records the delete date of entities by a given condition(s).
     * Unlike save method executes a primitive operation without cascades, relations and other operations included.
     * Executes fast and efficient DELETE query.
     * Does not check if entity exist in the database.
     * Condition(s) cannot be empty.
     */
```

softRemove:

```
   /**
     * Records the delete date of all given entities.
     */
```

An optional solution could be:

```
public async delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
    const talent: Talent = await this.talentRepository.findOne(id);

    if (!talent) throw new NotFoundException(`Talent with ID ${id} Not Found`);

    talent.deletedBy = "John Doe";

    await this.talentRepository.save(talent);
    await this.talentRepository.softDelete(talent);
}
```

Or within a transaction:

```
    public async delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
        const talent: Talent = await this.talentRepository.findOne(id);

        if (!talent) throw new NotFoundException(`Talent with ID ${id} Not Found`);

        talent.deletedBy = "John Doe";

        await this.talentRepository
            .manager
            .transaction(em => {
                await em.save(Talent, talent);
                return em.softDelete(Talent, talent);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM updates only `deletedAt` column when you use `softDelete()`

As an optimized version of other answers, you can update `deletedBy` or any other custom column you added by less DB calls(2) and less no of lines using this approach:

```
public async delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
    const talent: Talent = await this.talentRepository.createQueryBuilder().update(Talent).set({ deletedBy: "John Doe" }).where('id = :id', { id }).execute();

    if (!talent) throw new NotFoundException(`Talent with ID ${id} Not Found`);

    await this.talentRepository.softDelete(talent);
}
```

This snippet will run two DB update queries.